# SQLNestedException when connection pooling using Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

This is the `Resource` configuration for the `jdbc connection pooling` for mysql.

```
<Resource 
        abandonWhenPercentageFull="50" 
        auth="Container" 
        closeMethod="close" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        global="jdbc/gisdata" 
        initialSize="34" 
        logAbandoned="true" 
        maxActive="377" 
        maxIdle="233" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" 
        minIdle="89" name="jdbc/gisdata" 
        password="temp12345" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://URL:3306/zmaperp_final?allowMultiQueries=true" 
        username="root" 
        validationInterval="34000" 
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
/>
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
```

I am using the Tomcat instance on my system within Tomcat and have added the `mysql-connector` jar file as recommended:

UPDATE: I have updated the `jar` file as suggested by @Jan's answer. The error has changed to look like this:

```
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1398)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1679)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1395)
    ... 23 more
```

**Update**

Updated the connection properties:

```
<Resource 
            abandonWhenPercentageFull="50" 
            auth="Container" 
            closeMethod="close" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            global="jdbc/gisdata" 
            initialSize="10" 
            logAbandoned="true" 
            maxActive="25" 
            maxIdle="10" 
            maxWait="10000" 
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" 
            minIdle="5" 
            name="jdbc/gisdata" 
            password="temp12345" 
            removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
            testOnBorrow="true" 
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            url="jdbc:mysql:SERVER/zmaperp_final?allowMultiQueries=true" 
            username="root" 
            validationInterval="34000" validationQuery="SELECT 1;"
        />
```

I tried removing the `allowMultiQueries` option now but the connection is still giving me an error.

[image: Tomcat lib folder]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **Driver**, not the **Sources** :-)

Check the file name for your driver. You'll want

```
 mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
```

or with highlighting: You have mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-<strike>source</strike>.jar, you need mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-**bin**.jar
Good luck :-)

**Edit / Your Question changed**

```
message from server: "Too many connections"
```

You need to **reduce number of max / initial connections** to something moderate. I recommend

```
    maxActive="25" 
    maxIdle="10" 
    maxWait="10000" 
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" 
    minIdle="5"
```

for starters.

Comment: I changed the `jar` to the `bin`, however, the issue persists. I have restarted the server and I get a new error which says `Error preloading the connection pool`. I have updated the question with the new error

Comment: I have made the change and reduced the number of connections as suggested, the error persists.

Comment: I have updated the connection properties, should I remove `allow multiQueries` from the connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98300/discussion-between-vamsiampolu-and-jan).